# CSS @media não está funcionando

Tags: css, css3

quando o site fica menor de 600px, deveria ativar o @media, porém não entra

```
* {
    font-family:Arial;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #727272;
}
.topo {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
article {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.musicas {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #b9b9b9;
}
.track {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.namefile {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.control {
    width: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: tomato;
    }
    header .container {
        width: auto;
    }
    article .musicas {
        background-color: teal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Vc tem `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` no Head do HTML?

Comment: até tenho, mais tava faltando partes, nossa que burrice kkkkk, acho que preciso descansar

Comment: coloca como resposta que eu finalizo aqui

Comment: coloquei a resposta (-:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para as `media queries` funcionarem você deve ter essa tag no `head` do seu HTML:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```